# Grouping MySQL results to only allow a record to add to the total if the last one found is over two hours old

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently tracking actions performed by employees in a table, which has three rows: `id`, `user_id`, and `action_time`, `customer_id`. In order to track performance, I can simply pick an employee on a date, and count the actions they've performed, easy peasy.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `customer_id`) AS `action_count` 
FROM   `actions` 
WHERE  `user_id` = 1 
AND    DATE(`action_time`) = DATE(NOW())
```

However, I now wish to make it so that actions performed more than two hours apart will class as two actions towards the total. I've looked into grouping by `HOUR() / 2` but an action performed at 9:59 and 10:01 will count as two, not quite what I want.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you have a sequence of actions that each occur within 2 hours of each other, but over a cumulative time period of more than two hours (eg. actions at 10:00, 11:30 and 13:00) then should these count as one action or more than one?

Comment: To clarify more... Cust 1 @ 9:00, Cust 2 @ 9:20, Cust 1 @ 10:10, Cust 1 @ 11:02, Cust 3 @ 2:15, Cust 1 @ 2:25, Cust 2 @ 2:40, Cust 3 @ 5:10, Cust 4 @ 6:08 would be 4 "groups"... from 9-10:59 (2 customers), 11:02-1:01( 1customer), 2:15-4:14(3 customers), 5:10-6:09(1 customer), 6:08-8:07(1 customer) ??  Probably can be done with MySQL variables, but I'll have to test at home.

Comment: (Clarifying my earlier comment - for a given customer.)

Comment: @Mark In the example you specified, that would only count as a single action

Answer (score 0):

You must self-JOIN the *actions* table, try something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM (
  SELECT a1.id, ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a1.action_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a2.action_time))>=7200 
  AS action_time_diff FROM actions a1 JOIN actions a2 ON a1.user_id=a2.user_id) AS t 
WHERE action_time_diff = 1
```

Not sure if this works, perhaps you should provide more exact details about the table structure.